# RxJava dispose Observable in subscribe

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Are there any clear and smart solution to dispose observable from its subscribe method?
E.g. I have an `Observable.interval` that emits Long every second. In my subscribe method i want to check if 20 seconds gone than dismiss subscription.

```
val observable = Observable.interval(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { num ->

                    if(num == 20.toLong())
                    {
                        observable.dispose()//I cant call dispose here because variable 'observable' is not avaliable yet
                    }
                })
```

What is the easiest and right way to achieve this logic?

Comment: Did you try `takeUntil` or `takeWhile` operator? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html

Comment: Gralls thanks, yes takeUntil is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found one simple solution. Just divide variable declaration and initialization in to two steps.

E.g.

```
var observable:Disposable? = null
observable = Observable.interval(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { num ->

                    if(num == 20.toLong())
                    {
                        observable?.dispose()
                    }
                })
```